# data that is extracted from computers

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does in the following quote ***"to abstract"*** mean ***"to extract"*** ? And does the sentence containing it mean:

A graphic representation of data that is extracted from computers that exist in contemporary human societies?

Context:

> Cyberspace. A consensual hallucination experienced daily by billions
>   of legitimate operators, in every nation, by children being taught
>   mathematical concepts... A graphic representation of data abstracted
>   from banks of every computer in the human system. Unthinkable
>   complexity. Lines of light ranged in the nonspace of the mind,
>   clusters and constellations of data. Like city lights, receding...
>
> [William Gibson, Neuromancer](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/14638-cyberspace-a-consensual-hallucination-experienced-daily-by-billions-of-legitimate)

Comment: Which do you think has been "abstracted", the *representation* or the *data*?

Answer (score 1):

This is a computer science and mathematics question. First, I would rather use examples to explain the relationship of these two words.

In computer science, an abstract is a representation. There are quite a number of forms of abstracts.

An application programming interface (API) is an abstract. When we design a system, we design its abstract. We provide the specification of how other system interacts with it. When we create a library of functionalities, we first design the abstract, which specifies how software that use that library would interact with the functionality of the library.

As the specifier, I do not wish to care how you implement it. The API is a contract between the consumer and the supplier. The contract is an abstract of whatever you would do or need to do to satisfy that contract.

In Integrated Circuit (IC) design, each module of design are abstracts of how those modules will be fabricated, assembled, tested. A complex IC is designed from hundreds of such modules. They are joined together thro graphical representations on IC design software. The software will keep the abstracts of each module, such that when two modules are joined together, the design software would know if they can be compatibly joined together, and if not what measures need to be taken to join two modules together.

They are abstracts because after a design is completed, no IC would exist still. The design is an abstract with the recipes to the various stages of its manufacture.

Frequently, we represent the hierarchy of an organisation using a tree diagram aka organisational chart. The org chart is an abstract of the relationship of various personnel in the company.

We use graphed relationships to represent molecules. We draw lines between the member-atoms of molecules to document the type of interaction between them, like the covalent or ionic interaction. Certainly, a molecule does not look like the way we abstracted them to help us quickly and efficiently design our molecules.

Like joining two modules in IC design, when two atoms are joined together, their characteristics are changed, and our abstract representation has to document that. We also have to abstract the chain of processes of how we would actually join them. When two or three modules are joined together, they would form a macro-abstract - grouped abstract in its own right. When macro-abstracts join together, they form supermacro abstracts. We could use grouping algorithms to model their existence and behaviour. That model itself is an abstract representation.

Imagine the resulting complexity of assembling gazillions of modular abstracts. And we can zoom in or zoom out of that network of abstracts. And when it becomes so complex and unpredictable, we ultimately relent to address the abstract as a cloud.

To most people, abstract means complexity. Like describing a painting as "abstract". However, in Science and technology, abstract means simplification and reduction of a reality to its bare-bone skeletal, so that we document only the characteristics that we would use to analyse and synthesize them, without being hindered by unnecessary details. A caricature cartoon of Nixon and Kissinger is an abstract of their most pronounced features by not being clouded by other details, to be able to focus the audience to "innuendoically" pass them a message.

Extract means harvesting, pulling or sucking out. We could extract oil from tar sands, or extract oil out of a whale. Guantanamo Bay's existence seems to be to extract information out of terrorists or human assets of value.

In reverse-engineering a system, we would extract the abstract out of that system, to harvest the essential skeletal of its behaviour.

In forward-engineering, we have to construct the abstract, because there is no existing system from which we could extract an abstract. Rather, we would extract the desires and intention of muggles-operator-users of a system and construct an abstract representation, so that we could analyse and measure the intensity, criticality and viability of their needs. While depending on such an abstract to design the abstract of a desired system or equipment.

In Statistics, we extract the behaviour and characteristics of a population, whether they be traffic patterns in San Bernardino Valley, or the model of consumers of Amazon, or the characteristic product flow of a factory. From those extracts we construct an abstract behavioural model. We would extract voluminous amounts of data. From that data, we would use statistical abstraction methods, or equivalent grouping methods, to extract the dimensions of that data, which we then construct them into abstract components.

From those components we could predict, that when components interact, where and when bottlenecks occur in a factory. Or what combination of interaction of components we should avoid or encourage to optimise our business.

Therefore, abstraction may coincide with extraction, but not usually or always.

In a world filled with computers in phones, refrigerators, PCs, traffic lights, elevators, pace makers, in-vehicle, building environmental controllers, power grid controllers, etc, there would be a massive cloud of information, from which we could extract abstracts, and from those abstracts, construct other abstracts.

In data analysis, we use clustering algorithms. We statistically discover the principal dimensions of the information. And then each data point is located on the coordinates of this abstract multi-dimensional space. And then we groups pairs of data points by their closest proximity. A group thus abstracted, is then considered a macro-datapoint. Then we group these macro-datapoints to form larger groups. We recursively form larger and larger groups. We will visualise them like stars in a multidimensional sky. And soon we would form constellations of datapoints.

As we proceed towards the constellation formation, the number of lines and dimensions shrink. In the mathematical model, we can either zoom up to see the datapoint constellations, or zoom downwards to see the subdimensions. As we zoom downwards/inwards, the number of lines would increase and the interactions mind-boggling. As we zoom upwards, to see the constellations, we see the empirical interactions between super-super groups while ignoring all the innards of those supergroups/constellations. At each level, they have an abstract behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite. "Abstracted" means "copied and summarized" in this case. Look at the meanings numbered 6, 13, and 14:

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abstract?s=t

The word "extract" would have vaguely negative connotations in this case. One might get the impression that some of the data was taken from people's hard drives without asking permission.